# Appengine NodeJS Flexible logging-winston logs not printing

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, gcloud, winston

I have been using @google-cloud/logging-winston module for logging in appengine flexible environment.

But recently I noticed no logs are printing under **'winston_log'** logName, its only printing in **stout**, following is my configuration:

```
const logLevel = 'info'

const transports = [new Console({level: logLevel, colorize: isDevMode(), timestamp: isDevMode()})]
transports.push(LoggingWinston({level: logLevel}))

// application logger
const logger = new winston.Logger({ transports: transports })

logger.error('error test') // no logLevel
logger.info('app listening on port 8080') // no logLevel
logger.debug('debug test') // no logLevel
```

**Nothing is printing under 'winsont_log' logName**, all logs are printed only in console like below:

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are using **[console transport](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md#console-transport)** that is why you are getting logs inside the console window. Instead, use **[File transport](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md#file-transport)** to write logs in the log file.

Comment: i am using appengine environment , so file transport is not supported, and the log should get printed in both transports

Comment: Have you tried this library along with winston.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/winston-gae

Comment: i have seen that the library in under deprecation, so thats why opted for @google-cloud/logging-winston library